# Create multidimensional array from array in wordpress

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I would like to populate `$list` and instead of that sample data, have arrays with custom field  values for each of the ids. Like so:

```
foreach($idArr as $ID)
  array('.'get_post_meta($ID, 'name', true)'.'),
  array('.'get_post_meta($ID, 'email', true)'.')
  //and so on ...

}
```

`$idArr` contains post ids

```
print_r($idArr);
Array ( [0] => 242 [1] => 241 )

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly you can use  `get_post_custom();`.

```
$list = array();

foreach ( $idArr as $ID ) {
    $list[] = get_post_custom( $ID );
}
```

By doing so the structure you will get is

```
$list = array(
    0 => array(
        'key1' => array( [0] => 'value' ),
        'key2' => array( [0] => 'value2' ),
    )
);
```

The issue with this is each custom field can have multiple values so you get an array back instead of a string. It's the equivalent of `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'key', false );`. Adapt your code to work with this format.

Alternatively if you're looking for specific fields you could try:

```
$list = array();

foreach ( $idArr as $ID ) {
    $fields = get_post_custom( $ID );
    $values = array();

    // Select only the values you need and add them to the array. REPEAT as needed.
    if ( ! empty( $fields['email'][0] ) {
        $values[] = $fields['email'][0];
    } 

    $list[] = $values;        
}
```

The method above solves the issue in my first example whcih meant each field was an array rather than a string.

I'd probably want to give each array value a key as well. E.g. `$list[]…` becomes `$list[ $ID ]…`.

Comment: I need to save these to a csv file.

Comment: PHP has built-in functions for doing that.

Comment: yeah ... but that's the information i need to write to the csv file.

Comment: I'm happy help you solve a problem with some code you've written however I can't write all the code for you.

Comment: Got it. Your alternative works for me. Now how do I open a save file window and save the csv to my computer?